# multidimensional jax.isin()

Tags: python, set, jax

i am trying to filter an array of triples.
The criterion by which I want to filter is whether another array of triples contains at
least one element with the same first **and** third element. E.g

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
array1 = jnp.array(
  [
    [0,1,2],
    [1,0,2],
    [0,3,3],
    [3,0,1],
    [0,1,1],
    [1,0,3],
  ]
)
array2 = jnp.array([[0,1,3],[0,3,2]])
# the mask to filter the first array1 should look like this:
jnp.array([True,False,True,False,False,False])
```

What would be a computationally efficient way to achieve this mask using jax?
I am looking forward to your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by reducing over a broadcasted equality check:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
array1 = jnp.array(
  [
    [0,1,2],
    [1,0,2],
    [0,3,3],
    [3,0,1],
    [0,1,1],
    [1,0,3],
  ]
)
array2 = jnp.array([[0,1,2],[0,3,2]])  # note adjustment to match first entry of array1

mask = (array1[:, None] == array2[None, :]).all(-1).any(-1)
print(mask)
# [ True False False False False False]
```

XLA doesn't have any binary search-like primitive, so the best approach in general is to generate the full equality matrix and reduce. If you're running the code on an accelerator like a GPU/TPU, this sort of vectorized operation is efficiently parallelized and so it will be computed quite efficiently in practice.

Comment: Something worth considering is the memory complexity. Obviously this is not an issue for this example, but if `array1.shape[0]` and `array2.shape[0]` are O(N) where N >> 1, then this vectorised version is O(N^2) in memory (`jax.jit` does pick up some memory savings, but remains asymptotically O(N^2)). In cases such as these, the broadcast would need to be done in sequential batches (using an outer `jax.lax.map`).

Comment: jakevdp thanks for your answer. It solved my problem in the initial use case I had in mind. @DavidJ thanks for the additional comment! Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Memory profile the `mask` computation. The product of the size of the two arrays, multiplied by the integer byte size, must be bounded by your physical memory size to perform this fully vectorised. For example, if both arrays have ~2^15 elements this should be fine with 32GB RAM. If this is not the case, you'll need a sequential outer loop to ensure what is vectorised fits in memory.